# Set ViewEncapsulation.None to every component

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't like how Angular adds a `_ngcontent-*` in the elements of the HTML page, and since I don't really implement that functionality I remove it adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in my component. But since there are a lot of components and there will be more in my project, I was wondering if there's a way to set the encapsulation globally instead of modifying each component.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/sherweb/ngx-materialize/issues/222) to some research I have done and the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#members) about the `ViewEncapsulation` enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewEncapsulation` will not only allow to bind your contents from other components - it will also stop encapsulating your components `styles`  so if you remove the `style` or `styleUrls` from  your component decorator the encapsulation will be set to `none` by the compiler

Check this [doc](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation) for further queries

Next step you can restrict it while creating your components using angular cli

`ng generate component [name] --view-encapsulation=none`

This will create your component with the encapsulation property as none - you can check for some commands over [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)

Hope this helps - Happy coding:)

Answer (score -2):

You can try setting 'ViewEncapsulation.None' in app.component.ts which will be applicable for your whole project.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```